# web-scrape and extract only text and not number

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm new to this and I've been trying to web-scrape and extract only the text from an html and remove the associated citation in the form of [number]. Example: Centre-ville[5]

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you be able to share a sample of your data?

Comment: <table class="wikitable sortable">

<tbody><tr>
<th>Quartier</th>
<th>Habitants</th>
<th>Superficie</th>
<th>hab/ km²</th>
<th>Logements</th>
<th>hab/logement
</th></tr>
<tr>
<td>Centre-ville[5]</td>
<td>28 485</td>
<td>2,42 km²</td>
<td>11771</td>
<td>19 081</td>
<td>1.49
</td></tr>.  The [#] is in the <td> that I want to scrape. Thanks!

Comment: @carolche You mean just extract ```5``` from ```Centre-ville[5]``` ? And what have you done so far? Please post your code so that we can help you out.

Comment: Sorry, I actually haven't tried any code yet because I didn't even know where to start. I was looking for help everywhere but couldn't find any code that specifically focused on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to substitite '[something]' with '' by using sub()
Here, is complete code.

```
import re
def purify(txt):
    return re.sub("\[.+\]", "", txt)

txt = "rauan a sur[34]"
print(purify(txt=txt))
#rauan a sur
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp